# Path Location:Oracle.Driver (Oracle.DataAccess.dll) for Oracle 11g Standard Edition Release 2

Tags: nhibernate-mapping, oracle11gr2

I have installed Oracle 11g Standard Edition Release 2. I am working with nhibernate 2.2. I already spent lots of time but I could not find the location of Oracle Driver dll file (Oracle.DataAccess.dll) in the installed file.Please Help me. Thanks in advance.

Satadip

Answer (score 0):

Since 11.2 Oracle Data Provider for .NET ships with two sets of binaries

The Oracle.DataAccess.dll assembly is installed to the following locations:

.NET Framework 2.0:

ORACLE_BASE\ORACLE_HOME\odp.net\bin\2.x directory

.NET Framework 4:

ORACLE_BASE\ORACLE_HOME\odp.net\bin\4 directory

From the [Oracle Data Provider for .NET Developer's Guide 11g Release 2 (11.2.0.3)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/toc.htm)

Obviously for the files to be there you must have included the Oracle Data Provider for .NET as part of your Oracle Installation or downloaded Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) from OTN instead.